# How to calculate time difference between SQL time and PHP time

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, time

I have set times in SQL in this format: 2016-01-03 12:13:26. 
I would like to calculate the number of hours and minutes (if hours<1) going from NOW() to that particular SQL time. 
I've been looking at all the different threads here but I can't seem to grasp how to convert PHP different time formats to SQL's.

This is the code I've been using, but this will only give me back hours up to 12, and minutes also. Don't know how to use it with days.

```
$now = date("d/m/Y h:i:s");
$commentime = strtotime($SQLTIME);
$timetocomment = $now - $commentime;
```

For instance, this code will yield "12 hours ago" for data I posted 24 hours ago to SQL.
How can I do it?    Thank you.

Comment: i think the problem is the $now = date("d/m/y h:i:s") try to convert it to 24 hours not 12 hours, also go check the time in database see if its 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion to use `date()` in this format `date("Y-m-d h:i:s")`. Than you will get the complete difference in an `array`.

```
function dateDifference($date_1 ,$date_2)
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval;
}

$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$sqlTime = "2016-01-03 12:13:26";
$DateDiffArr = dateDifference($now,$sqlTime);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($DateDiffArr);
```

**Result Is:**

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 22
    [i] => 45
    [s] => 55
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

In resultant `array`, you can get the all difference as you need like in years, months, days, minutes, seconds etc.